# How to convert standard error of the mean (SEM) into a percentage change

Tags: mean, error, percentage

I have performed a t-test between groups, but I only have Mean, SEM, and N. Now I would like to look at the percentage change between these two groups, and compare this percentage change to another data set. What becomes of SEM? I do not have individual data points, so I cannot compare each data point's % change. I can calculate % change in mean, but do not know what to do for SEM.

For instance:

-DMSO: mean = 65.8, SEM = 5.1, n = 36. (Baseline)

+DMSO: mean = 71.53, SEM = 3.84, n = 36. (With Drug)

vs.

-100uM PHT: mean = 67.31, SEM = 6.82, n = 36 (Baseline)

+100uM PHT: mean = 13.45, SEM = 2.3, n = 36 (With Drug)

Each separate group is repeated measures. I can calculate easily that the % change relative to baseline (100%) is 108.7% for DMSO and 19.98% for PHT. However, I do not know what to do to SEM. I would like to compare the percentage change of PHT to DMSO.